# Fetch request hitting localhost instead of api (swagger)

Tags: javascript, localhost, fetch-api

I'm trying to use fetch / post, to send form data to a swagger api hosted by my university. Unfortunately, when I click send the data is sent to localhost instead of the provided https path.

I have changed the port to 8080, allowed unsigned requests and the accepting of external connections.

The code is still being sent to http://localhost:8080/ which produces a 404 error.

What do I need to do to send the data to the correct destination?

Below you can see my code used to try to send the data.

```js
fetch('https://correct-path.com/api/v1/data', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'TOKEN',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

Screenshot of the logged network error

[image: Screenshot of the logged network error]

Overview of the header incl. error

[image: Overview of the header incl. error]

Comment: What does this have to do with Webstorm? How do you know the request is sent to `localhost`?

Comment: I'm using Webstorm to write the code. The request is sent to localhost because localhost is showing up when I check the Networks in the devtools/console. The localhost error is  in the same line the URL in the code is supposed to show up. The overview for the network error shows:

URL: https://correct-path.com/api/vi/data
URL: http://localhost:8080/
Status: 404 Not Found
Quelle: Netzwerk
Adresse: ::1:8080
Initiator: 
form.js:106

Comment: Your editor isn't important. It's not clear what you mean by _"the overview for the network editor"_, could you please [edit] your question to provide a screenshot?

Comment: I've added the screenshots.

Comment: I have never seen a duplicate URL header. That's very odd

Comment: Because the duplicate header isn't in the code I still think it might have something to do with the Webstorm setup.

Comment: No, the code runs in your browser. Webstorm is just an editor. Are you running any browser extensions? If so, try disabling them

Comment: I have tried it in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. No extensions on firefox. 404 error at localhost 8080 in all three browsers. 
Also, fetching data (not fetch/post) from the same api works perfectly fine.

Comment: What happens if you execute the code in your browser console directly, ie copy / paste the code into your console?

Comment: A wild thought but perhaps the OPTIONS preflight request gets redirected to localhost by your server?